# Firefox error "Parts of this page are not secure (such as images)" RDS 2016

Tags: iis

In my company we use the Web Portal to log users into the RDS2016 Terminal. Firefox has been giving me the error for some time: "Parts of this page are not secure (such as images)". I know this is related to hardcoded http instead of https and pointing to favicon.ico. I also know that in Wordpress it can be easily solved with e.g. Really Simple SSL. On a server we use common IIS in windows server 2016. I can't find a favicon link to fix it from http to https. The favicon.ico file is in / root.

Comment: In firefox you can see in Inspect Element=>Network Tab=>Domain Columns. and also please check in Console tab too.

Comment: Thank you. When I watch the error details in console, I see that the problem is Mixed content in Favicon.ico url on the login.aspx page. But on this page I can't find http link to favicon.ico

Comment: Unfortunately the problem still exist, any ideas?